# Under ARC, need to set nil to all the strong member when unload the viewcontroller? Is that a must?

Tags: ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting

Suppose I have a view controller like this:

```
@interface ControllerA : viewcontroller{
    NSString * __strong a;
}

@end
```

and in `viewDidLoad` function I set

```
a = [[NSSString alloc] init];
```

And in another ControllerB,

```
{
    ControllerA * controllerA = [[ControllerA alloc] init];
}
```

Will controllerA's member be released?

Comment: I don't know the context, but controllerA in ControllerB's code will be released when it goes out of scope.

Comment: By the way, I you don't need the `__strong` qualifier because ivars are `strong` by default.

Comment: @RobertRyan I know. I just want to make my question more clear. Thank you for reminding.

Comment: The ivar won't be cleaned up if running with zombies enabled in iOS 5. Otherwise it will. See [Technical Note Q&A 1758](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1758/_index.html).

Comment: @Rob Thank you for all the updates. It makes me clearer. It seems I am beginning to forget most of the memory things after using ARC. Don't know good or bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the string pointed to by `a` will be released when `controllerA` is deallocated. You don't need to set it to `nil` yourself.

[Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW11) is currently the place to look for more information about working with ARC. One important point that it makes is that you may still need a custom `-dealloc` if your class needs to do anything *other than* releasing instance variables when it's instances are deallocated.

Comment: Again, true for local vars, not ivars.

Comment: @RobertRyan, what do you mean? Ivars are absolutely released automatically during dealloc under ARC.

Comment: @RobertRyan You're incorrect. As RobNapier says, ivars (and properties) are certainly released by ARC in `-dealloc`. The docs are very clear on this: ["The compiler also generates appropriate dealloc methods for you."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW13). See my comment at Rob's answer for more.

Comment: @Caleb Quite right. But I swear that I have a project for which when I put this code (as a brand new controller, no other code associated with it), it's not being released automatically. I'll diagnose this later and post my findings.

Comment: @Caleb It turn out that I was experiencing a known bug when turning on zombies in pre-iOS 6 apps. In that scenario, ivars are not released. It's fixed effective iOS 6 and also doesn't manifest itself when you turn off zombies.

Answer (score 4):

You never need to set a variable to nil in ARC unless you want to ensure its deallocation as soon as possible (i.e. [myObject release] under non-ARC code).  All iVars will be automatically released when the object is deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a well known bug in iOS 5 when using ARC and Zombies enabled that can prevent ivars from being released: [Technical Q&A QA1758](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1758/_index.html).

Otherwise, the ivars will be automatically released.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:**

After spending, quite literally, several hours diagnosing and documenting the failure of ivars to be released in my iOS 5 project this morning, I discovered that instance variables are not released in ARC projects if zombies are turned on and run on iOS 5. About to update my answer with these remarkable findings, quite independently, [Calin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104534/calin) pointed out to me that this is well known behavior. [Technical Q&A QA1758](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1758/_index.html). Thanks Calin!

My sample project is at https://github.com/robertmryan/arc-problem-project

**Update:**

I had previously claimed that this was incorrect and that vars and properties would not be deallocated unless you set them to `nil`. I provided the below code as an example. This is taken from a real ARC test project and I even recreated it with another view controller with absolutely nothing in it except the code below to confirm. After a well-deserved chorus of dissents, I put this code sample in a new project, and the ivar was deallocated, as it should be.

So it must be something about the project in question. I've since taken absolutely everything out of that project except the below code (and the view controller that performs the push segue, so that I can pop back to it to demonstrate the deallocation), and the problem persists. If I copy the code (and storyboard) to a new project, it works fine. Very, very strange and I will dig into this more. If you want to see my project, it's at https://github.com/robertmryan/arc-problem-project. Maybe someone else can see what the problem is. I know I can just discard this project (it wasn't even a production app, just a testing platform), but it's worrying that ARC's dealloc can just magically not work properly.

Anyway, to be clear, your ivars *are* released as the parent object is released. I don't know why my is not releasing in the case below, but that's immaterial to the original question.

```
//  ArcTestViewController.m

#import "ArcTestViewController.h"

#pragma mark - IvarObject

@interface IvarObject : NSObject
@end

@implementation IvarObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

@end

#pragma mark - ArcTestViewController

@interface ArcTestViewController ()
{
    IvarObject __strong *_ivarObject;
}
@end


@implementation ArcTestViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    
//    _ivarObject = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    _ivarObject = [[IvarObject alloc] init];
}

@end
```

When I do this with the `=nil` statement in the `dealloc` method commented out, I see the following on my console:

> 2012-07-12 10:33:33.644 test4[36045:11903] -[ArcSimpleTestViewController dealloc]

When I uncomment that `=nil` statement in my `dealloc`, I see the following:

> 2012-07-12 10:35:23.117 test4[36083:11903] -[ArcSimpleTestViewController dealloc]
>
> 2012-07-12 10:35:23.119 test4[36083:11903] -[IvarObject2 dealloc]

To my retraction above, when I put this same code in a new project, I see the deallocs whether I nil or not.

Rob Napier provided the code sample below (I appreciate him and others taking the time), but even the above code works fine when I put it in another project, but in my current project, it doesn't deallocate properly!

---

Update from Rob Napier: Simpler example (all in one file) that demonstrates how this works. Put this in a file and compile as indicated:

```
//  arc.m
//  Compile with:
//      clang -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation -o arc arc.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#pragma mark - IvarObject

@interface IvarObject : NSObject
@end

@implementation IvarObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

@end

#pragma mark - PropertyObject

@interface PropertyObject : NSObject
@end

@implementation PropertyObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

@end


#pragma mark - ArcTest

@interface ArcTest : NSObject
{
    IvarObject __strong *_ivarObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) PropertyObject *propertyObject;

@end


@implementation ArcTest

@synthesize propertyObject = _propertyObject;

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

//    _ivarObject = nil;
//    _propertyObject = nil;
}

- (void)assignStuff
{
    _ivarObject = [[IvarObject alloc] init];
    self.propertyObject = [[PropertyObject alloc] init];
}

@end

int main () {
    ArcTest *test = [[ArcTest alloc] init];
    [test assignStuff];
    test = nil;
    NSLog(@"End program");
}
```

Comment: The above code won't quite compile as written, but if I build the same example in a simple Foundation app, I get dealloc's for ArcTest, PropertyObject and IvarObject, just as expected. This is a key feature of ARC. ivars and properties absolutely *will* be released when the owning object is deallocated. They will be deallocated if that was the last retain.

Comment: @RobNapier I don't know why it won't compile for you as I cut and pasted directly from my project. What compile error do you get? (I edited this to add the missing final `@end`.) I have a view controller that pushes to this view controller, which instantiates the ivar and the property, and when it pops back to the previous view controller, I see the the `ArcTestViewController` dealloc NSLog, but _neither_ the `IvarObject` nor `PropertyObject` dealloc NSLogs.

Comment: Your answer doesnt make sense to me.  Whether or not dealloc is called has nothing to do with its internal state.  Apple has stated outright in its developer videos that ivars will be released as part of the dealloc timeline.  ARC would be dumb if it didnt.  The point is to write less management code, so making the user explicitly nil variables during dealloc does not help that.

Comment: @RobertRyan, I suspect you are creating a retain loop somewhere (or otherwise retaining the ivar and property), or that there is more code. I will edit your answer with an example of a simpler program (all in one file) that demonstrates.

Comment: I see what you are doing now but it conflicts with the available information

Comment: Not just available information, but testing. ARC absolutely does release ivars when the object deallocates. That may not cause the objet to deallocate if there are other retainers. But in no case do you need to nil ivars prior to deallocation in order for them to be released.

Comment: @RobertRyan I tried your code and got the expected messages from all three `-dealloc` methods. If you're not seeing them, it's likely that your `_ivarObject` and `_propertyObject` ivars aren't set. To rule out all the possible view-loading problems, try setting them instead in `-initWithNibName:bundle:options:`.

Comment: @borrrden Apparently, ivars don't get released when zombies are turned on. See [TN 1758](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1758/_index.html). Wow. That had been annoying me for months, and I had set this project aside assuming it was corrupted somehow. A mixture of relief and frustration to see it was such a simple issue.

Comment: @Rob Yes, that made sense to me the first time I figured it out but I was also frustrated.  Actually I think it is quite amazing that they were able to fix it, since I assumed the object needed to stay alive in order to get the information provided by zombies.